# How could I see dialogs or type words when running a bat file taking my python file?

Tags: python, printing, types, batch-file

My bat file as following, the last line is the most important.

```
echo off

REG.exe Query HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0 > checkOS.txt

Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    Echo "This is 32 Bit Operating system"
    path =C:\PROGRA~1\MYAPP\APPBIN;C:\PROGRA~1\MYAPP\APPLIB
) ELSE (
 PATH=C:\PROGRA~2\MYAPP\APPBIN;C:\PROGRA~2\MYAPP\APPLIB
    Echo "This is 64 Bit Operating System"
)

  myapp.exe -embed -pyfile template.py
```

And template.py

```
print "Please show the print"
ask=raw_input("Type the name: ")
```

My expectation is when I double click my bat file, I could see the print command and 
type command somewhere. How could I do that?

P.S: If I solely run python file through my myapp.exe, it's able to see "Please show the print" and "Type the name: " on python command window.

Comment: Do you mean to have `@echo off` instead of `echo off` at the beggining of the bat?

Comment: nothing changed, thank you anyway.

Comment: Is `myapp.exe` a console application? How is `myapp.exe` executing the python script.  Most likely, you will need to make sure your application is outputting to the stdout stream and not just displaying within it's console window.

Comment: No, it's a very complete industrial app which allows to use python to read their data file.

Comment: My confusion comes from not understanding what you intend with your find statement, other than to use either 64bit or 32bit executables. If you want your user to see the phrase "this is a [32|64] bit os" then try a PAUSE statement on the line before myapp.exe.

Comment: No, this is not problem with [32] or [64] bit os, b/c I am dealing with many computers with 32bit and 64bit. Maybe I am confusing you.

Comment: I am able to run pyfile by myapp.exe by using bat, however, when I add codes like template.py. How could I type words since there is now command line or interface for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `myapp.exe -embed -pyfile template.py` to  `start C:\Python25\python C:\template.py`
It's good to go!